# Twitter Bootstrap modal: How to remove Slide down effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to change the Twitter Bootstrap Modal window animation from a slide down effect to a fadeIn or just display without the Slide? I read through the documentation here:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

But they don't mention any options for changing the modal body slide effects.

Answer (score 366, accepted):

Just take out the `fade` class from the modal div.

Specifically, change:

```
<div class="modal fade hide">
```

to:

```
<div class="modal hide">
```

---

**UPDATE:** For bootstrap3, the `hide` class is not needed.

Comment: seriously, this is the actual answer... c'mon S.O.

Comment: Though the OP did ask for how to make it fade in so some of those answers are correct for the alternate formation of the question.  Guess it's just a bad question because it's really 2 questions in one and no one has answered both questions in one answer.

Comment: hi all, haven't viewed this answer in a while, i just switched the answer to this one. cheers!

Comment: wouldn't "taking out the fade class" require modifying the plugin? how is that better than the answers below that suggest modifying the css?

Comment: Taking the fade out also make it work better on a mobile device.  It doesn't try to center it vertically.   It's OK for the best answer to be the simplest one.

Comment: I'm with drogon - How are you supposed to do this without modidfying the bootstrap source? What if you're loading from a CDN?

Comment: You don't have to modify the bootstrap sources. You only have to modify your html. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @umassthrower is correct. Only how to have no transition is answered. The question of how to fade but not drop-down from the top is not covered by this answer.

Comment: This may be the correct answer for this very specific question but many people may be looking for a way to modify how the modal appears. I want to slide in from the left for a modal sidebar. I will be trying to clone the fade and related classes but putting them in a new slide-in class(es). Hopefully this will not require changing bootstrap itself. If so it should be a bug, this is a pretty fundamental requirement.

Comment: I don't get how this is the correct answer... it makes the modal pop in with no fade, and OP has asked to remove the SLIDE, but not the FADE...

Comment: This is good, but it should be noted that the `'shown.bs.modal'` event is never called when you remove the `fade` class.

Comment: I'm waiting to keep the fade and remove the slide as well and this answer is not helpful. It's strange bootstrap used their fade class to also handle the slide effect for the modal as the fade is a entirely separate in their CSS.

Comment: This solution removes fade effects from modal

Comment: This does not answer original question, which is to keep the fade but remove the slide-in effect

Answer (score 36):

The modals used by the bootstrap use CSS3 to supply the effects and they can be removed by eliminating the appropriate classes from modals container div:

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="myModal">
   ....
</div>
```

As you can see this modal has a class of `.fade`, meaning it is set to fade in and`.in`, meaning it will slide in. So just remove the class related to the effect you wish to remove, which in your case is just the `.in` class.

Edit: Just ran some tests and it appears that that is not the case, the `.in` class is added by javascript, though you can modify he slideDown behavior with css like so:

```
.modal.fade {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3v2zg/91/show/)

Comment: You should also add it to the backdrop: `modal.fade, .modal-backdrop.fade` etc...

Comment: it's probably better to edit the component-animations.less file, for the reason David mentions.

Comment: the fade class is optional, there is a better (and preferred per BS documentation) answer by Rose below

Comment: @umassthrower this answer is pretty old, at the time of writing that choice did not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure that comment is correct as BS 2.0 was released 3 months before that answer and I removed fade from my modals when using v2.0 last summer.  Perhaps they didn't change the documentation until after that.  Dunno.

Comment: In any event.  If you want to change to a different transition then you can try some of the other answers as they answer part 2 of the OP's 2 part question.  If you just want to remove the effect just remove the class.

Comment: @umassthrower back then removing the fade class also removed the fade in transition for the backdrop, leaving you with a choppy appearance. Don't know how it is today since I have not tested it in a while. My answer just removed the slide effect and left the backdrop fade in intact, per the question.

Comment: @umassthrower Just tested it, it still happens when the fade class is removed :/ odd, http://jsbin.com/ojiwax/1

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it still happens?  The jsbin you posted doesn't have an effect happening.  Perhaps this has turned into a communication problem rather than a technical problem because your test shows exactly what I said.

Comment: @umassthrower im a bit confused towards your remark, per the question OP simply wants to remove the slide down effect, not the fade in effect of the backdrop. Removing the `.fade` class removes all effects, including the backdrop fade in effect. If the `.fade` class is removed, it removes all effects, but op just wanted the slide in effect removed and I provided a solution for that.

Comment: The OP asked how to change "from a slide down to a fade in".  That statement implied that there wasn't a fade in in the first place.  As it turns out now that I've gone and checked the BS site, that implication was incorrect.  My B.

Answer (score 30):

If you like to have the modal fade in rather than slide in (why is it called `.fade` anyway?) you can overwrite the class in your CSS file or directly in `bootstrap.css` with this:

```
.modal.fade{
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s linear, none;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s linear, none;
    -ms-transition: opacity .2s linear, none;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s linear, none;
    transition: opacity .2s linear, none;
    top: 50%;
}
```

If you don't want any effect just remove the `fade` class from the modal classes.

Comment: The *top: 50%* seems to be causing trouble when the dialog closes. The dialog seems to be opening in the same place as before; but just before closing, for a split second it moves to center and then closes. Atleast in Chrome. Has anybody else noticed this too?

Comment: @lorem monkey - cheers, wanted the fade but not the slide. If anyone wants the scss/compass version... 
.modal.fade {@include transition(opacity .2s linear, none);}

Comment: @mohitp Instead of "top: 50%", I'm using "top: 25%". I also added .modal.fade.in { top: 25%; } Seems to have done the trick for me. Not certain why this works since I don't have the "in" class in my modal.

Comment: @dkrape the `in` class is added by Bootstrap.js

Comment: This is the right answer, answering both parts of the question.

Answer (score 26):

I believe that most of these answers are for bootstrap 2. I ran into the same issue for bootstrap 3 and wanted to share my fix. Like my previous answer for bootstrap 2, this will still do an opacity fade, but will **NOT** do the slide transition.

You can either change the modals.less or the theme.css files, depending on your workflow. If you haven't spent any quality time with less, I'd highly recommend it.

for less, find the following code in `MODALS.less`

```
&.fade .modal-dialog {
  .translate(0, -25%);
  .transition-transform(~"0.3s ease-out");
}
&.in .modal-dialog { .translate(0, 0)}
```

then change the `-25%` to `0%`

Alternatively, if you're using just the css, find the following in `theme.css`:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

and then change the `-25%` to `0%`.

Comment: I would override these styles in a custom stylesheet instead of editing Bootstrap's stylesheet/Less.

Comment: this is the ONLY simple CSS solution to get FADE w/o slide. thx.

Answer (score 18):

I solved this by overriding the default `.modal.fade` styles in my own LESS stylesheet:

```
.modal {
  &.fade {
    .transition(e('opacity .3s linear'));
    top: 50%;
  }
  &.fade.in { top: 50%; }
}
```

This keeps the fade in / fade out animation but removes the slide up / slide down animation.

Comment: thank you. I ended up using 10% instead of 50%, and reduced the transition from .3s to .25s which seems a bit smoother to me.

Comment: Opening and closing a modal multiple times moves it up the page over time.

Answer (score 14):

I have found the best solution that **removes the slide but leaves the fade** is by adding the following css in a css file of your chosing which is invoked after the bootstrap.css

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog 
{
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;

    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    -o-transform: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer for Bootstrap 3 in order to keep the fade but remove the slide down

Comment: This solution works fine for Bootstrap 4 too. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I didn't like the slide effect either. To fix this all you have to do is make the the `top` attribute the same for both .modal.fade and modal.fade.in. You can take off the `top 0.3s ease-out` in the transitions too, but it doesn't hurt to leave it in. **I like this approach because the fade in/out works, it just kills the slide**.

```
.modal.fade {
  top: 20%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.modal.fade.in {
  top: 20%;
}
```

If you're looking for a bootstrap 3 answer, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143444/twitter-bootstrap-modal-how-to-remove-slide-down-effect/19777522#19777522)

Comment: The top two non-LESS examples above neglect the ".modal.fade.in" declaration, which makes the modal jump around a bit on closing. This one works great. Here it is in practice: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrape/4EwFq/

Comment: This mostly works but I am seeing a bright blue horizontal line appear (in all of Safari, Firefox and Chrome) about 32px above my Modal when it appears.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the fade class and if you want more animations to be perform on the Modal just use animate.css classes in your Modal.

Answer (score 2):

you can also overwrite bootstrap.css by simply removing "top:-25%;"

once removed, the modal will simply fade in and out without the slide animation.

Answer (score 2):

look at http://quickrails.com/twitter-bootstrap-modal-how-to-remove-slide-down-effect-but-leaves-the-fade/

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog 
{
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    -o-transform: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with bootstrap 3 and the Durandal JS 2 modal plugin. This question was on top of Google results and as none of the answers above is working for me I thought I'd share my solution for future visitors.

I override the default Bootstrap's Less code with this in my own less:

```
.modal {
  &.fade .modal-dialog {
    .translate(0, 0);
    .transition-transform(~"none");
  }
  &.in .modal-dialog { .translate(0, 0)}
}
```

That way I am left with only the fade effect, and no slideDown.

Answer (score 1):

```
.modal.fade, .modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: That will remove animation from showing and hiding. Works fine for me with Angular-Bootstrap ui also.

Answer (score 1):

The question was clear: remove *only* the slide: Here is how to change it in Bootstrap v3

In modals.less comment out the translate statement:

```
&.fade .modal-dialog {
  //   .translate(0, -25%);
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove 'fade' class from modal class

```
class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg"
```

as

```
class="modal bs-example-modal-lg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to update this. Most of you have not completed this issue. I'm using Bootstrap 3. none of the fixes above worked.

to remove the slide effect but keep the fade in. I went into bootstrap css and (noted out the following selectors) - this resolved the issue.

```
 .modal.fade .modal-dialog{/*-webkit-transform:translate(0,-25%);-ms-transform:translate(0,-25%);transform:translate(0,-25%);-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .3s ease-out;-moz-transition:-moz-transform .3s ease-out;-o-transition:-o-transform .3s ease-out;transition:transform .3s ease-out*/}

 .modal.in .modal-dialog{/*-webkit-transform:translate(0,0);-ms-transform:translate(0,0);transform:translate(0,0)*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS works for me - Using Bootstrap 3.
You need to add this css after boostrap styles -

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog{
    -webkit-transition-property: transform; 
    -webkit-transition-duration:0 ; 
    transition-property: transform; 
    transition-duration:0 ; 
}

.modal.fade {
   transition: none; 
}
```