# Dialog in Bootstrap4Xpages on Iphone bad rendering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I've the bootstrap4Xpages plugin working.
When displaying a dialog , this renders fine on a pc but bad on an Iphone in vertical position.( look at the example)
The user isn't able to see the left part of the dialog.

I wrapped a div around the dialog control hoping to be able to change the css , but this doesn't seem to work.
The example code :

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<xe:dialog id="dialog1" title="TEST on an Iphone">

    <xe:dialogContent id="dialogContent1">
    test this is a test Modal dialog test
    <xp:br></xp:br>
     is this working or not that is the question, Not on an Iphone vertically I guess!!!
    </xe:dialogContent>
    <xe:dialogButtonBar id="dialogButtonBar1">
    <xp:button
                        value="Ok"
                        id="button3"
                        themeId="Button.Primary">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" />
                        <xp:eventHandler
                            event="onclick"
                            submit="true"
                            refreshMode="partial"
                            refreshId="dialog1">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dialog1").hide()}]]></xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    </xe:dialogButtonBar>
</xe:dialog>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Does the modal have animation? Prior to the existence of the bootstrap4xpages plugin, I had a similar issue with modals on the iPhone (and Android).  Turning off the animation made them appear centered.  I don't know why this helped, but it did so I left it off.

Comment: I should add that the modal had animation turned on by default.  (this was bootstrap 2 though)  I had to turn it off prior to getting it to display correctly on smaller devices.

Comment: How do I know if it has animation ? And more important how do I turn it off ?

Comment: Does the Modal appear to come in from the top of the screen, or does it just appear?  I will research the setting on how to turn off.  (I should add that I don't know how Xpages4Bootstrap might have implemented this)

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to come from the top , it seems to fade in

Comment: Remove the word "fade" from the class and it will remove all the animation.  It isn't there by default like I said, just used most of the examples.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143444/twitter-bootstrap-modal-how-to-remove-slide-down-effect

Comment: Seems a bug in the bootstrap4xpages plugin: it sets a fixed width on the dialog. I've reported it here: https://github.com/OpenNTF/Bootstrap4XPages/issues/70

Comment: A popup dialogue is the VERY anti-thesis of a mobile UI. While you can investigate why it isn't working, I strongly suggest you look for an alternate approach! The inplace dialog seems to be a better fitting approach. Mobiles are different from desktops!

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found this project :
[bootstrap-modal](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal)

I tried the bootstrap 3 version , the stacked one , which renders fine on all devices, also the Iphone.