# Instantly display a modal when the form is submitted (before validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using a bootstrap validator from (https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/blob/master/js/validator.js) and I'm trying to instantly display a modal 'loading' box when the submit button is pressed on a form. I've achieved this by doing the following:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    showLoadingModal();
    if (!event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm(this);
    } else {
        hideLoadingModal();
    }
});
```

However I'm getting a problem where there is a small gap of time (under a second) between clicking the button and the modal being displayed. I'm assuming this delay is caused by the time taken validating all the fields on the form of which there are quite a lot.

This therefore leads me to believe that the validator 'form submit' is being executed before my code and I should be doing something different to call the showLoadingModal()

Edit:

I've added some logging into the js to work out what happens and when.  I've also moved the showLoadingModal() into a 'button clicked' event to ensure it happens before form submit.  Here's the order my messages get displayed:

button clicked
before show modal
after show modal
form submitted
about to validate
<--Modal appears now-->

Comment: Well, did you try showing it on a click event that doesn't trigger validation, to check that it is indeed validation that is taking time?

Comment: I've tried it on 'mouseup' of the button press and the delay is still there, I'm not sure why, any ideas?

Comment: What are you using for your modal dialog? some library?

Comment: Just the built in twitter bootstrap version ie $('#myModal').modal({ keyboard: false });

Comment: @MasterScrat have a look at my edit, I tried moving it to a click event as you suggested and still get the delay

Comment: Maybe it's due to Bootstrap animating the window while showing it... Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143444/twitter-bootstrap-modal-how-to-remove-slide-down-effect

Answer (score 0):

set a delay of 300ms before submitting your form

```
var event;
var formobj;
('form').on('submit', function (event) {
showLoadingModal();
event = event; //save event to be used later 
formobj = this;
setTimeout(function() 
{
     if (!event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm(formobj );
      } else {
          hideLoadingModal();
      }
},300);
return false; //Prevent normal submission of the form so that the dialog box is visible
});
```

I am assuming submitForm(this) is the function that does the form posting causing the page to reload

Just a thought, hope it helps!