# Change the Bootstrap Modal effect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I found this [Demo](http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/)  ,

The demo have a pretty effect, I wonder if any one have way to apply this demos to be easy to use with bootstrap Modal 
specially the first one (Fade In & Scale)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143444/twitter-bootstrap-modal-how-to-remove-slide-down-effect

Comment: I know this is an old post, but some might want to implement this without scrubbing the source, so here is a link directly to the article/tutorial - with source code: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/

Comment: A better one can be found in here- https://codepen.io/antoncabon/pen/WxQLbM

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If you take a look at the bootstraps `fade` class used with the modal window you will find, that all it does, is to set the `opacity` value to `0` and adds a transition for the `opacity` rule.

Whenever you launch a modal the `in` class is added and will change the `opacity` to a value of `1`.

Knowing that you can easily build your own `fade-scale` class.

Here is an example.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.fade-scale {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
  -o-transition: all .25s linear;
  transition: all .25s linear;
}

.fade-scale.in {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade-scale" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**-- UPDATE --**

This answer is getting more up votes lately so i figured i add an update to show how easy it is to customize the BS modal in and out animations with the help of the great [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library by
*Daniel Eden*.

All that needs to be done is to include the stylesheet to your `<head></head>` section. Now you simply need to add the `animated` class, plus one of the entrance classes of the library to the modal element.

```
<div class="modal animated fadeIn" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" ...>
  ...
</div>
```

But there is also a way to add an out animation to the modal window and since the library has a bunch of cool animations that will make an element disappear, why not use them. :)

To use them you will need to toggle the classes on the modal element, so it is actually better to call the modal window via JavaScript, which is described [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript).

You will also need to listen for some of the modal events to know when it's time to add or remove the classes from the modal element. The events being fired are described [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

To trigger a custom out animation you can't use the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute on a `button` inside the modal window that's suppose to close the modal. You can simply add your own attribute like `data-custom-dismiss="modal"` and use that to call the `$('selector').modal.('hide')` method on it.

Here is an example that shows all the different possibilities.

```js
/* -------------------------------------------------------
| This first part can be ignored, it is just getting
| all the different entrance and exit classes of the
| animate-config.json file from the github repo.
--------------------------------------------------------- */

var animCssConfURL = 'https://api.github.com/repos/daneden/animate.css/contents/animate-config.json';
var selectIn = $('#animation-in-types');
var selectOut = $('#animation-out-types');
var getAnimCSSConfig = function ( url ) { return $.ajax( { url: url, type: 'get', dataType: 'json' } ) };
var decode = function ( data ) {
  var bin = Uint8Array.from( atob( data['content'] ), function( char ) { return char.charCodeAt( 0 ) } );
  var bin2Str = String.fromCharCode.apply( null, bin );
  return JSON.parse( bin2Str )
}
var buildSelect = function ( which, name, animGrp ) {
  var grp = $('<optgroup></optgroup>');
  grp.attr('label', name);
  $.each(animGrp, function ( idx, animType ) {
    var opt = $('<option></option>')
    opt.attr('value', idx)
    opt.text(idx)
    grp.append(opt);
  })
  which.append(grp) 
}
getAnimCSSConfig( animCssConfURL )
  .done (function ( data ) {
  var animCssConf = decode ( data );
  $.each(animCssConf, function(name, animGrp) {
    if ( /_entrances/.test(name) ) {
      buildSelect(selectIn, name, animGrp);
    }
    if ( /_exits/.test(name) ) {
      buildSelect(selectOut, name, animGrp);
    }
  })
})


/* -------------------------------------------------------
| Here is were the fun begins.
--------------------------------------------------------- */

var modalBtn = $('button');
var modal = $('#myModal');
var animInClass = "";
var animOutClass = "";

modalBtn.on('click', function() {
  animInClass = selectIn.find('option:selected').val();
  animOutClass = selectOut.find('option:selected').val();
  if ( animInClass == '' || animOutClass == '' ) {
    alert("Please select an in and out animation type.");
  } else {
    modal.addClass(animInClass);
    modal.modal({backdrop: false});
  }
})

modal.on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  var closeModalBtns = modal.find('button[data-custom-dismiss="modal"]');
  closeModalBtns.one('click', function() {
    modal.on('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function( evt ) {
      modal.modal('hide')
    });
    modal.removeClass(animInClass).addClass(animOutClass);
  })
})

modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function ( evt ) {
  var closeModalBtns = modal.find('button[data-custom-dismiss="modal"]');
  modal.removeClass(animOutClass)
  modal.off('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend')
  closeModalBtns.off('click')
})
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css');

select, button:not([data-custom-dismiss="modal"]) {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <select id="animation-in-types">
        <option value="" selected>Choose animation-in type</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <select id="animation-out-types">
        <option value="" selected>Choose animation-out type</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Open Modal</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal animated" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-custom-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-custom-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about the close effect?

Comment: What is with the close effect?

Comment: Is this possible with backdrop as well?

Comment: Version Note: Great work! For Bootstrap 4, the class `.in` should be replaced with `.show`.

Comment: In and out animations are no longer populating.

Comment: How big is `animate.css`? I can't find that information anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 14):

Pure [Bootstrap 4](http://getbootstrap.com/) solution with [CSS 3](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/).

```html
<div class="modal fade2" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.fade2 {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .2s linear;
    display: block !important;
}

.fade2.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```js
$('#exampleModal').modal();

function afterModalTransition(e) {
  e.setAttribute("style", "display: none !important;");
}
$('#exampleModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    setTimeout( () => afterModalTransition(this), 200);
})
```

[Full example](https://jsfiddle.net/bgbruno/knzpa4vq/)

---

Ref

- Thank you @DavidDomain.

Comment: How about the close effect?

Comment: I updated it for you @HamedH - see the code #css "display: block !important;" and #js "hide.bs.modal",

Answer (score 4):

I copied model code from [w3school bootstrap model](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) and added following css. This code provides beautiful animation. You can try it.

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
     -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
     -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
     -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
     transform: scale(0.1);
     top: 300px;
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
     transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal.fade.in .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modal In Out Effect with **Animate.css** and **jquery** Very easy and short code.

In HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="DirectorModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog bounceInDown animated"><!-- Add here Modal COME Effect "Animate.css" -->
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this bellow jquery code i got from: https://codepen.io/nhembram/pen/PzyYLL

i am modify this for regular use.

jquery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // BS MODAL OPEN CLOSE EFFECT  ---------------------------------
        var timeoutHandler = null;
        $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var anim = $('.modal-dialog').removeClass('bounceInDown').addClass('fadeOutDownBig'); // Model Come class Remove & Out effect class add
            if (timeoutHandler) clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
            timeoutHandler = setTimeout(function() {
                $('.modal-dialog').removeClass('fadeOutDownBig').addClass('bounceInDown'); // Model Out class Remove & Come effect class add
            }, 500); // some delay for complete Animation
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 5.2 version it's enough to change `transform` property value of `.modal.fade .modal-dialog` class into `scale(0)` or any other from your wish.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest (5.x) bootstrap, you can control the animation using css only. For example, this will show a "zoom in/out" effect:

```cs
.modal.modal-zoom.fade:not(.show) .modal-dialog {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

Just add `modal-zoom` to the element with the `modal` class.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS file. It attaches a CSS animation to the `.modal` class when `.show` is added.

```
.modal.show {
    animation: modalOpen .3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes modalOpen  {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    1% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
        transform: scale(.5);
    }
    45% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.95);
        transform: scale(.95);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

You might want to turn the default modal animation off by simply removing `fade` from your modal HTML.

`<div class=" modal >fade< " id="" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">`

Answer (score 0):

```
 body{
  text-align:center;
  padding:50px;
}
.modal.fade{
  opacity:1;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
   -webkit-transform: translate(0);
   -moz-transform: translate(0);
   transform: translate(0);
}
.btn-black{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  background:#222;
  padding:10px 20px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

    <div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline" style="position:absolute; top:40%; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%);">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Entrances</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="entrance">
            <optgroup label="Attention Seekers">
              <option value="bounce">bounce</option>
              <option value="flash">flash</option>
              <option value="pulse">pulse</option>
              <option value="rubberBand">rubberBand</option>
              <option value="shake">shake</option>
              <option value="swing">swing</option>
              <option value="tada">tada</option>
              <option value="wobble">wobble</option>
              <option value="jello">jello</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Bouncing Entrances">
              <option value="bounceIn" selected>bounceIn</option>
              <option value="bounceInDown">bounceInDown</option>
              <option value="bounceInLeft">bounceInLeft</option>
              <option value="bounceInRight">bounceInRight</option>
              <option value="bounceInUp">bounceInUp</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Fading Entrances">
              <option value="fadeIn">fadeIn</option>
              <option value="fadeInDown">fadeInDown</option>
              <option value="fadeInDownBig">fadeInDownBig</option>
              <option value="fadeInLeft">fadeInLeft</option>
              <option value="fadeInLeftBig">fadeInLeftBig</option>
              <option value="fadeInRight">fadeInRight</option>
              <option value="fadeInRightBig">fadeInRightBig</option>
              <option value="fadeInUp">fadeInUp</option>
              <option value="fadeInUpBig">fadeInUpBig</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Flippers">
              <option value="flipInX">flipInX</option>
              <option value="flipInY">flipInY</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Lightspeed">
              <option value="lightSpeedIn">lightSpeedIn</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Rotating Entrances">
              <option value="rotateIn">rotateIn</option>
              <option value="rotateInDownLeft">rotateInDownLeft</option>
              <option value="rotateInDownRight">rotateInDownRight</option>
              <option value="rotateInUpLeft">rotateInUpLeft</option>
              <option value="rotateInUpRight">rotateInUpRight</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Sliding Entrances">
              <option value="slideInUp">slideInUp</option>
              <option value="slideInDown">slideInDown</option>
              <option value="slideInLeft">slideInLeft</option>
              <option value="slideInRight">slideInRight</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Zoom Entrances">
              <option value="zoomIn">zoomIn</option>
              <option value="zoomInDown">zoomInDown</option>
              <option value="zoomInLeft">zoomInLeft</option>
              <option value="zoomInRight">zoomInRight</option>
              <option value="zoomInUp">zoomInUp</option>
            </optgroup>

            <optgroup label="Specials">
              <option value="rollIn">rollIn</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
       </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Exits</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="exit">
            <optgroup label="Attention Seekers">
              <option value="bounce">bounce</option>
              <option value="flash">flash</option>
              <option value="pulse">pulse</option>
              <option value="rubberBand">rubberBand</option>
              <option value="shake">shake</option>
              <option value="swing">swing</option>
              <option value="tada">tada</option>
              <option value="wobble">wobble</option>
              <option value="jello">jello</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Bouncing Exits">
              <option value="bounceOut">bounceOut</option>
              <option value="bounceOutDown">bounceOutDown</option>
              <option value="bounceOutLeft">bounceOutLeft</option>
              <option value="bounceOutRight">bounceOutRight</option>
              <option value="bounceOutUp">bounceOutUp</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Fading Exits">
              <option value="fadeOut">fadeOut</option>
              <option value="fadeOutDown">fadeOutDown</option>
              <option value="fadeOutDownBig">fadeOutDownBig</option>
              <option value="fadeOutLeft">fadeOutLeft</option>
              <option value="fadeOutLeftBig">fadeOutLeftBig</option>
              <option value="fadeOutRight">fadeOutRight</option>
              <option value="fadeOutRightBig">fadeOutRightBig</option>
              <option value="fadeOutUp">fadeOutUp</option>
              <option value="fadeOutUpBig">fadeOutUpBig</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Flippers">
              <option value="flipOutX" selected>flipOutX</option>
              <option value="flipOutY">flipOutY</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Lightspeed">
              <option value="lightSpeedOut">lightSpeedOut</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Rotating Exits">
              <option value="rotateOut">rotateOut</option>
              <option value="rotateOutDownLeft">rotateOutDownLeft</option>
              <option value="rotateOutDownRight">rotateOutDownRight</option>
              <option value="rotateOutUpLeft">rotateOutUpLeft</option>
              <option value="rotateOutUpRight">rotateOutUpRight</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Sliding Exits">
              <option value="slideOutUp">slideOutUp</option>
              <option value="slideOutDown">slideOutDown</option>
              <option value="slideOutLeft">slideOutLeft</option>
              <option value="slideOutRight">slideOutRight</option>
            </optgroup>        
            <optgroup label="Zoom Exits">
              <option value="zoomOut">zoomOut</option>
              <option value="zoomOutDown">zoomOutDown</option>
              <option value="zoomOutLeft">zoomOutLeft</option>
              <option value="zoomOutRight">zoomOutRight</option>
              <option value="zoomOutUp">zoomOutUp</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Specials">
              <option value="rollOut">rollOut</option>
            </optgroup>

          </select>
       </div>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>
    </form>

      <a class="btn btn-black " href="http://demo.nhembram.com/bootstrap-modal-animation-with-animate-css/index.html" target="_blank">View FullPage</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function testAnim(x) {
        $('.modal .modal-dialog').attr('class', 'modal-dialog  ' + x + '  animated');
    };
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
      var anim = $('#entrance').val();
          testAnim(anim);
    });
    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
      var anim = $('#exit').val();
          testAnim(anim);
    });
    </script>

<style>
body{
  text-align:center;
  padding:50px;
}
.modal.fade{
  opacity:1;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
   -webkit-transform: translate(0);
   -moz-transform: translate(0);
   transform: translate(0);
}
.btn-black{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  background:#222;
  padding:10px 20px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.custom-modal-header
{
    display: block;
}
.custom-modal .modal-content
{
    width:500px;
    border: none;
}
.custom-modal
{
    display: block !important;
}
.custom-fade .modal-dialog {
    transform: translateY(4%);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    will-change: transform;
}
.custom-fade.in .modal-dialog  {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
<div class="modal custom-modal custom-fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Title</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>My cat is dope.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Sure (Meow)</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For Bootstrap 4, the `.in` should be replaced with `.show`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.fade-scale {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
  -o-transition: all .25s linear;
  transition: all .25s linear;
}

.fade-scale.in {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade-scale" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

A [riot.js](http://riotjs.com/) solution:

My riot.js Example nests the animated-modal tag inside an order profile tag.

Note, this assumes jquery and riot.js is loaded before.

animated-modal tag contents:

```
<a id='{ opts.el }' href="" class='pull-right'>edit</a>

    <div class="modal animated" id="{ opts.el }-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="animatedModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button onclick={ cancelForm } id='{ opts.el }-cancel-1' type="button" class="close" ><span>&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="animatedModal">{ opts.title }</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <yield/>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button onclick={ cancelForm } id='{ opts.el }-cancel-2' onclick={ cancelForm } type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
            <button onclick={ saveForm } type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var self = this
    self.modalBtn = `#${opts.el}`
    self.modal = `#${opts.el}-modal`
    self.animateInClass = opts.animatein || 'fadeIn'
    self.animateOutClass = opts.animateout || 'fadeOut'
    self.closeModalBtn = `#${ opts.el }-cancel-1, #${ opts.el }-cancel-2`
    self.animationsStr = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend'

    this.on('mount',function(){
        self.initModal()
        self.update()
    })

    this.initModal = function(){
        modal = $(self.modal)
        modalBtn = $(self.modalBtn)
        closeModalBtn = `#${ opts.el }-cancel-1`

        modalBtn.click(function(){
            $(self.modal).addClass(self.animateInClass)
            $(self.modal).modal('show') 
        })

        $(self.modal).on('show.bs.modal',function(){
            $(self.closeModalBtn).one('click',function(){
                $(self.modal).removeClass(self.animateInClass).addClass(self.animateOutClass)

                $(self.modal).on(self.animationsStr,function(){
                    $(self.modal).modal('hide') 
                })
            })
        })

        $(self.modal).on('hidden.bs.modal',function(evt){
            $(self.modal).removeClass(self.animateOutClass)
            $(self.modal).off(self.animationsStr)
            $(self.closeModalBtn).off('click')
        })
    }

    this.cancelForm = function(e){
        this.parent.cancelForm()
    }

    this.showEdit = function(e){
        this.parent.showEdit()
    }

    this.saveForm = function(e){
        this.parent.saveForm()
    }

    dashboard_v2.bus.on('closeModal',function(){
        try{
            $(`#${ opts.el }-cancel-1`).trigger('click')
        }catch(e){}

    })
</script>
```

And the Profile Tag to nest in:

profile tag contents:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="eshop-product-body">

                <animated-modal>
                    title='Order Edit'
                    el='order-modal-1'>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                            <form id='profile-form'>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Organization</label>
                                    <input id='organization' type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Contact</label>
                                    <input id='contact' type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Phone</label>
                                    <input id='phone' type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input id='email' type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </animated-modal>

                <h3>Profile</h3>

                <ul class='profile-list'>
                    <li>Organization: { opts.data.profile.organization }</li>
                    <li>Contact: { opts.data.profile.contact_full_name }</li>
                    <li>Phone: { opts.data.profile.phone_number }</li>
                    <li>Email: { opts.data.profile.email }</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var self = this     

        this.on('mount',function(){

        })

        this.cancelForm = function(e){

        }

        this.showEdit = function(e){

        }

        this.saveForm = function(e){

        }
    </script>
```