# How to change bootstrap modal open transition effect?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to change the bootstrap modal open effect. The default effect is not so good.

Can we have any way to change it?

Also I want to open the modal in center not on the top.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168234/9971404, which has more up-to-date answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the easiest way to do it . just by adding below css.

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
-webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
-moz-transform: scale(0.1);
-ms-transform: scale(0.1);
transform: scale(0.1);
top: 300px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal.fade.in .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> first you need a style sheet whose link is beneath the bootstraps `css` link
>
> you got two main classes in css, namely `.modal.fade` and `modal.in`
>
> `.modal.fade` represents your modal's initial state
>
> `.modal.in` represents your modal's final state when it gets into the viewport
>
> then in your style sheet paste the code below
>
> you can just copy the code below and tweak it's behavior.

```css
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
       -o-transition:      -o-transform .3s ease-out;
          transition:         transform .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(180deg) !important;
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(180deg) !important;
       -o-transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(180deg) !important;
          transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(180deg) !important;
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%) rotate(360deg) scale(1.2, 1.2) !important;
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 50%)  rotate(360deg) scale(1.2, 1.2) !important;
       -o-transform: translate(0, 50%)  rotate(360deg) scale(1.2, 1.2) !important;
          transform: translate(0, 50%)  rotate(360deg) scale(1.2, 1.2) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: note if you want the modal to be in the middle of the viewport then change the `translate(0, 50%)` to `translate(0, 100%)` in `.modal.in`  class

Answer (score 2):

Centred modal with effect

```css
.anil {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;/*opening speed*/
  -o-transition: all 1s linear;/*opening speed*/
  transition: all 1s linear;/*opening speed*/
}

.anil.in {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);/*size of the div to scal after .in class attached on opening modal*/
}
 .modal {
        top:30%!important;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Centered with animation</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal anil" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: please run demo in full page mode i have tested it before posting..it is showing scroll bar in compact mode but in mobile n full mode browser it be fine

Answer (score -1):

http://dixso.github.io/custombox/
you can get help here
It has given step wise explaination