# ng-bootstrap modal animation

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

The fade class doesn't appear to work on the ngb-modal.

I've looked at trying to apply my own animation to the modal but the modal template is obviously injected into modal dialogue by ng-bootstrap e.g. I don't have access to the modal dialogue. I only have access to the template:

```
<template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header card-header" style="border-radius: 10px;">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Form</h4>
 </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> </div>
...etc
</template>
```

I need to apply my animation to the top level dialogue otherwise just bits of the modal animate. If I apply it to the template it blows up.

Any idea how I would animate the whole modal??

Comment: Animations are not supported ny ng-bootstrap yet, but they will be in the future. Contributions to the project are welcome (although the big-picture design hasn't been done yet, AFAIK).

Comment: My last company dropped ng-bootstrap after 1 year due to little progress and still no animating modals - a sign that something isn't right with the library. I'm amazed it still doesn't support it all this time later.

Answer (score 22):

Here is simple solution. Just put it in style.css

```
/* modal animation */
.modal-content{
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {transform: scale(0.5)}
  75%  {transform: scale(1.1)}
  100% {transform: scale(1)}
}
```

Comment: This only has animation for the modal entrance and not exit which is not ideal.

Comment: @DarrylMendonez Do you have any other way to do it?

Comment: I managed to do it (animation on close) following this simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329484/4834117

Answer (score 11):

You need to add animation css class to global styles and add NgbModalOptions.

**styles.css: // or whatever is your global css**

```
.modal-holder{
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {transform: scale(0.5)}
  100% {transform: scale(1)}
}
```

**modal.component.ts**

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent, {windowClass: 'modal-holder', centered: true});
```

Enough talk, you can see example on:

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-66n3nl)**

Answer (score 3):

> Here is the exact replica of **FADE IN - OUT** animation with **SLIDE DOWN** as of
>   [bootstrap 4.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/)

**SOLUTION 1: Initialize animation in constructor**

app.component.ts:-

```
import { NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {
    NgbModalRef.prototype["c"] = NgbModalRef.prototype.close;
    NgbModalRef.prototype.close = function(reason: string) {
      document.querySelector(".modal-backdrop").classList.remove("show");
      document.querySelector(".modal").classList.remove("show");
      setTimeout(() => {
        this["c"](reason);
      }, 500);
    };
    NgbModalRef.prototype["d"] = NgbModalRef.prototype.dismiss;
    NgbModalRef.prototype.dismiss = function(reason: string) {
      document.querySelector(".modal-backdrop").classList.remove("show");
      document.querySelector(".modal").classList.remove("show");
      setTimeout(() => {
        this["d"](reason);
      }, 500);
    };
  }
  open(basic) {
    this.modalService.open(basic);
  }
```

app.component.html :-

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">Basic Modal</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p>Toggle a modal via TypeScript by clicking the button above.</p>
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button type="button" (click)="open(basic)" class="btn btn-outline-primary block btn-lg">
                  Launch Modal
                </button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <ng-template #basic let-modal>
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel1">Basic Modal</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" tabindex="0" ngbAutofocus>
                            <h5>Check First Paragraph</h5>
                            <p>Oat cake ice cream candy chocolate cake chocolate cake cotton candy dragée apple pie.
                                Brownie carrot cake candy canes bonbon fruitcake topping halvah. Cake sweet roll cake
                                cheesecake cookie chocolate cake liquorice.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modal.close('Accept click')">Accept</button>
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                    <!-- / Modal -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

styles.scss :-

```
// modal animation
@keyframes modal-fade {
  from {
    top: -50px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.modal {
  top: -100px;
  animation: ease-in-out .3s modal-fade;

  &.show {
    top: 0;
  }
    .modal-body {
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
  }
}
```

stackblitz link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-boostrap-modal-animation-with-constructor)

**SOLUTION 2:**
**initalize animation in individual modal call**

app.component.ts :-

```
import { NgbModal } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
  constructor(private ngbModal: NgbModal) {}

  open(content: any, config?: any) {
    let modal = this.ngbModal.open(content, config);
    let instance = (modal as any)._windowCmptRef.instance;
    setImmediate(() => {
      instance.windowClass = "custom-show";
    });

    let fx = (modal as any)._removeModalElements.bind(modal);
    (modal as any)._removeModalElements = () => {
      instance.windowClass = "";
      setTimeout(fx, 250);
    };

    return modal;
  }
```

app.component.html :-

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">Basic Modal</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p>Toggle a modal via TypeScript by clicking the button above.</p>
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button type="button" (click)="open(basic)" class="btn btn-outline-primary block btn-lg">
                  Launch Modal
                </button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <ng-template #basic let-modal>
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel1">Basic Modal</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" tabindex="0" ngbAutofocus>
                            <h5>Check First Paragraph</h5>
                            <p>Oat cake ice cream candy chocolate cake chocolate cake cotton candy dragée apple pie.
                                Brownie carrot cake candy canes bonbon fruitcake topping halvah. Cake sweet roll cake
                                cheesecake cookie chocolate cake liquorice.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modal.close('Accept click')">Accept</button>
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                    <!-- / Modal -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

styles.scss :-

```
// animation style 
// --------------------------
.modal {
    &.show .modal-dialog {
        transition: 0.25s all;
        // opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(0, -5vh);
    }

    &.custom-show .modal-dialog {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
  .modal-body {
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
  }
}
```

stackblitz link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-boostrap-modal-animation)

Comment: thank u. this solution helped me to have animation on the close event too; other solutions work only for show =)

Comment: The good news is `ng-bootstrap` is planning for `animation` support !!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fade.modal {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

I don't know if this will work for you but i fixed it by adding this in the main css