# ng bootstrap modal with Angular animation ':leave' not working?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Why my exit animation 'leave' isn't working?
Animation for enter works perfectly but for leave(exit) is not working?
Please check my code and give me hint?

```js
      animations: [
        trigger('bubbleGrow', [
          transition(':enter', [
            animate('1000ms ease-in-out',  keyframes([
              style({transform: 'scale(0.5)'}),
              style({transform: 'scale(1)'}),
            ]))
          ]),
          transition(':leave', [
            animate('1000ms ease-in-out',  keyframes([
              style({transform: 'scale(1)'}),
              style({transform: 'scale(1.1)'}),
              style({transform: 'scale(0)'})
            ]))
          ]),
        ])
      ]


     constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private activeModal: NgbActiveModal){}


      close() {
        this.activeModal.close();
      }
```

```html
    <div class="modal-body" [@bubbleGrow]>
      Here is my code in modal....
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()" >
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: The issue is, you are using a ng bootstrap modal, that is rendered to appear via Angular rendering thats why ":enter" is triggered, but is removed via Bootstrap logic. You ":leave" trigger will not be triggered, since your angular render lifecycle will not register it as "leaving", no animation will be happening. 
You could  do a workaround with a close delay "ngClass" with animation have a fade out animation.

Comment: Oop? How to do it ?

Comment: Just take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610974/ng-bootstrap-modal-animation

Comment: I see it but , this way not close dialog and set two dialog opened..

Comment: @Luxusproblem I am looking this but i am don't know what is problem ?
Animation fade in work, but fade out no work. I need fade out..

Answer (score 1):

So if you want a animation for the fadeout you need a delay, and a animation.
First create a css-class with a animation:

```
@keyframes fadeout{
0%{  transform:scale(1);}
50%{ transform:scale(1.1);}
100%{ transform:scale(0);}
}

.fade-out{
 animation: fadeout 2s linear;
}
```

Then create a delay in your close() method and apply the animation via "ngClass"
component:

```js
export class YourClass{
      // this is to mark if you are about to close the modal, to trigger the animation
      public isClosing = false;

      constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private activeModal: NgbActiveModal){}


      close() {
        // here you "mark" the closing state
        isClosing=true;
        // create a delay of 2 seconds. Otherwise the animation will not be applied
        // because the modal will be closed instantly
        timer(2000).subscribe(()=>{
         this.activeModal.close();
        }
      }
}
```

In your html :

```html
    <div class="modal-body" [ngClass]="{'fade-out':isClosing}" [@bubbleGrow]>
      Here is my code in modal....
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()" >
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

This will start the animation, when "isClosing" is set to true.

`[ngClass]="{'fade-out':isClosing}"`

This is a workaround. But should do the deal.