# How to make animation for in/out of model in ng bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am not able to make out animation like I did for in animation.

I tried this

```
@keyframes fadeout{
0%{  transform:scale(1);}
50%{ transform:scale(1.1);}
100%{ transform:scale(0);}
}

.fade-out{
 animation: fadeout 2s linear;
}
```

this is my In animation code below:

```
@keyframes modal-fade {
  from {
    top: -390px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    top: -230px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.modal {
  top: -230px;
  animation: ease-in-out .3s modal-fade;

  &.show {
    top: -230px;
  }
    .modal-body {
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to make my model in top position, it is in center of page, to make it in top, I used top property, but with minus value, i want to avoid minus value. Is there any way to do it?

```
.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: -230px;
}
```

Comment: I managed to solve the issue following this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329484/4834117

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ng-bootstrap" **animation** option

Add this line to your code :

```
 this.modalService.open(content, { size: "sm", animation: true });
```