# Bootstrap modal: change animation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, sass

I haven't used bootstrap for a while and am now working on a project with bootstrap 4.6 +
It would appear that the animation is set by scss:

> Change animation
> The $modal-fade-transform variable determines the transform state of .modal-dialog before the modal fade-in animation, the $modal-show-transform variable determines the transform of .modal-dialog at the end of the modal fade-in animation.

> If you want for example a zoom-in animation, you can set
> $modal-fade-transform: scale(.8).

So I assumed just adding the variable to my scss would do the trick... what am I missing here??

```
$modal-fade-transform:scale(0.8);
```

Comment: I am also new to scss, so maybe I am missing something else fundamental?!

Comment: Hope this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168234/change-the-bootstrap-modal-effect/46095533) for changing bootstrap modal animation may help you.