# Disable fade bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to disable the fade of a modal in bootstrap, but it will not work what ever I do, I have tried the below code but sitll not luck, I have looked all over google but no information on this I have noticed, except the 2 css things I have tried in the below code.

```
.dont-fade {
    trasition: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I just want to disable the fade of a modal, and just have it like a div ontop of the whole page, without the fade.

Heres my html of my modal

```
<!-- Information on user popup -->
<div id="banModal" class="modal" role="dialog" style="">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Welcome!</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Hello, here is some test</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: I would look at this and post your related code if this doesn't help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143444/twitter-bootstrap-modal-how-to-remove-slide-down-effect

Comment: That is all the code I have, its not my fault that google is useless in finding this.

Comment: Your code for the actual modal (HTML/CSS/JS).

Comment: You don't appear to have actually applied the .dont-fade class to anything

Comment: provide a fiddle and reproduce the issue , so that we  can help